# Detecção do Scroll em uma página, adicionando e removendo classes

Tags: javascript

Bom, estou tentando fazer com que o `header` de uma página, receba ou perca uma classe, dependendo da posição da página, alguém poderia me informar o que está errado, e me ajudar a corrigir ?

```
window.onscroll = function() {

    var mobileTransp = document.getElementById('mobile-header');

    if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
        mobileTransp.classList.remove('on-top');
    }
    else{
        mobileTransp.classList.add('on-top');
    }

};
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: não está funcionando

Comment: Não está adicionando a classe?

Comment: não estava, mas acabei de resolver

Comment: Sugiro que poste sua solução na resposta. =)

Comment: pronto :3 obrigado pela prontidão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, uma solução foi adicionar o evento a uma função separada

```
window.onscroll = function() {scroll()};

function scroll(){

    var mobileTransp = document.getElementById('mobile-header');

    if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
        mobileTransp.classList.remove('on-top');
    }
    else{
        mobileTransp.classList.add('on-top');
    }
};
```

Comment: Boa tarde, soh me informe se funcionou.. fiquei curioso... abração!!

Comment: @kaputtz, não rolou não, mas fizeram o procedimento de outra forma, usando python, por isso encerrei a pergunta

Comment: tá show também! obrigado tchê!